# Vue.js dynamically Map JSON to Class without vue.Set or direct assignment in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

It's a simple question: "Can I map a JSON response to a class without specifically enumerating the fields, either with `vue.set`, or by passing parameters to the class, and directly assigning them?" It seems to me this is possible.

In React I can just map the data to the class.

So:

- Can I perform the map in `vue`/`vuex`? (assuming the correct syntax?)
- Am I stuck with `vue.set` or manual assignment?
- Is there a better package than Vue-Model out there if not?

The data returned:

```
{
    abc: "Some Text", 
    def: 9999.999, 
    ghi: false
}
```

The set of fields Needed:

```
function anItem(payload){
  this.abc = "";
  this.def = 0;
  this.ghi = false;
  this.notices = [];
  this.selected = false;
  this.is_updating = false;
}
```

The mutator

```
const mutations = {

  setStuff (state, payload) {
    /*this.state.myList.items = payload;*/ <- this works, of course.

    this.state.mylist.items = payload.map(a => new anItem(a)) <-- syntax here?
  },

};
```

Comment: What is wrong? I don't understand what you wanted and is not achieving.

Comment: Your `anItem` constructor is not expecting any params. Is this intentional?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. "...vue.js has a problem identifying added fields"

Comment: @skribe : see vue.js api under vue.set for explanation.

Comment: @sklingler93 Sorry man. Typo. Thanks.

Comment: @acdcjunior  I was unclear. Sorry.  It's a simple question: "Can I map a json response to a class without specifically enumerating the fields, either with vue.set, or by passing parameters to the class, and directly assigning them?"  It seems to me this is possible.  But then again, I might just be confused. ;)

Comment: all: at present I am assigning the values to the properties directly within the class via the parameter.

Comment: What like [mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/core-concepts.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument as initial values when constructing the object:

```
function anItem(payload){
  this.abc = payload.abc;  // changed this line
  this.def = payload.def;  // changed this line
  this.ghi = payload.ghi;  // changed this line
  this.notices = [];
  this.selected = false;
  this.is_updating = false;
}
```

And, then, change the mutator to pass such argument:

```
const mutations = {

  setStuff (state, payload) {
    this.state.mylist.items = new anItem(payload);
  },

};
```

Comment: That's it.  Thank you. ;)